# Прокручивать изображения назад jQqeury

Tags: jquery, javascript, изображения

С помощью товарища [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) был сделан слайдер, я немного его "кастрировал", вперед прокручивает отлично, а вот назад так и не понял. Господа, профессионалы по $, подскажите куда смотреть в прокрутке назад?

Вот фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/ySQRm/

Простите ещё вопрос, немного не в тему: может ли `<img />` быть `display: inline-block;` не противоречит ли это логике html,css?

Comment: "*... профессионалы по $ ...*" - это банкиры что ли? ))

Comment: Да нет же, jQuery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверно, [что-то в этом роде](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ySQRm/1/) - **не правильно!**

**UPD** [Так будет вернее](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ySQRm/2/)

Comment: съедает одну картинку, на next - все три, а когда back - только 2(

Comment: Угу... Не учел нюансы. Обновил ответ

Comment: там небольшой баг, если быстро нажимать, то порядок картинок перепутается.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/ySQRm/3/